# New react-native project won't load on iOS or android

Tags: react-native

On Mac OS X 10.14

Creating a new project with:

```
react-native init project
```

It builds the new project with the following list: https://pastebin.com/ED8qd0Ee

I run npm install to update anything.

Then I run `react-native run-android` The project builds and sends to device but I get an error there and the MetroBundler opens but all I get is Process terminated. Press  to close the window.

Im not sure what the issue is? I had no problem running a test app a week ago. I get back to it today and this.

On iOS, the app never builds on the device. The metro bundler again terminates immediately and the process reads off an infinite list of errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-native init project` this command create the project with latest versions so try to create project with previous versions like this `react-native init newproject --version react-native@0.54.4` 
you can choose any version here is mine

```
"react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.8",


"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

also check this code in .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ]
}
```

Run this command in your project `rm -r node_modules` it will delete node_modules folder in your project and change your package.json file and Run Command `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Is there some issue with 0.58.0 with Macs or just some bug on my end?

Comment: yes actually 0.58.0 is not statable now with some of its internal devDependencies.......there is no issue with Mac i am also using it